# Webwörter neu erfinden - Für google, duckduckgo, photoshop

Tags: word-choice, etymology

Please provide the equivalent german words for the following terms.

1. google (verb)
2. photoshopped (verb and abjective)
3. duck it (from duckduckgo.com - brand new)

Is there any urban dictionary (apart from dict.cc) for the german language? If this doesn't exist, why not create one? I mean, report to Duden or Pons. Just to widen the vocabulary to meet modern requirements.

Comment: I am not sure this question is a good fit for SE

Comment: These terms are often used in daily life. That's why, I wanted to know if the words do exist in this context. If not, then Duden/Pons or the German edition of urban dictionary should invent one. Am I wrong in my opinion? However, do you know the answer?

Comment: "to google" = googlen // "to photoshop" = photoshoppen // "to duck it" = ducken – However, the last one won't be ever used. The search engine is quite old but it's not in use.

Comment: you might want to change your opinion on the last word. ;-) just visit the website and check the settings/einstellungen option. Especially in Germany or in Scandinavian countries, where the privacy is still being considered as a basic human right.

Comment: „ich habe eure Seite *gefälltmirt* und ...“ habe ich mal gesehen (anstelle des *geliket*).

Comment: I prefer using the English words. Beware constructions like "downgeloadet". :/

Comment: @Em1 Achtung! "googlen" (l vor e) ist falsch! Richtig ist "googeln" (e vor l) und das obwohl die Suchmaschine "Google" (l vor e) heißt.

Comment: 2.: Etwas gimpen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, you can turn any noun into a verb pretty much by adding the ending "-en" or just conjugating it and using it in the position of a verb.

> Ich kühlschranke meine Küche.
>
> Ich infinitesimalrechnunge vor mich hin.

You can also do that to any English noun.

> Ich habe gestern ganz viel ge-iced-lattet.

It is not by any means correct German. But whether or not someone understands it depends on whether or not the person knows the words (and on context, as in the iced latte example). Sometimes journalists do stuff like that for stylistic reasons.
The pattern itself is pretty clear and everyone should get "verb". Based on that we have

- googeln , photoshoppen and possibly duckduckgoen (or shorts of that, although this site is pretty much unknown around here)

Similarly you can make up "tumblern", "facebooken", "whatsappen"... it doesn't matter.

Now, as for the dictionary. German is a bit more conservative than English so before such a word makes it into a dictionary like Duden it must have pretty much "made it" (be widespread, in spoken and written). I was surprised to see that "to photoshop" is in the Oxford dictionary.
But I don't see any reason to rush it. A word is a word because people use it and understand it - not because it's in the dictionary. And it's an English word anyway, so why would you need it in there to begin with?

Comment: Well put. As for the dictionary thing, unlike the English-speaking media, german media tends to be more conservative, in a way, not to be well-known for creating exotic words, unless they're present in the dictionaries. I respect that german is a very old classic language. why not create new ones?

Comment: @javafan Laziness/simplicity is not a prime directive of German, if such a thing exists. There are perfectly legitimate ways to say these things: "bei/mit Google suchen", "mit Photoshop bearbeiten" or "bei Tumbler einstellen". Arguably, German has more sophisticated tools for combining words and structuring sentences, so there is not as much a need for condensing concepts into single words as there is in English.

Comment: I think it should be 'infinitesimalrechne' since Rechnung is noun derived from a verb.

Comment: @konkret... no doubt, that would be better, but there is no "it should be" and "better" isn't the point. The only point is that it feels like a verb.

Answer (score 0):

So for to google there is a german world called "googlen" used in "etwas googeln" (http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/googeln). I think words like "photoshopped" or "duck it" don't have to be in German language. You can just replace them with "etwas bildbearbeiten" or "etwas suchen". Apart from that you are allowed to use any word indifferent if it is in the Duden or not. Every of these words like "to google" or "photoshopped" are just advertisment for the companies behind those words.

Comment: Du hast einmal "googlen" (l vor e) und vier Wörter später "googeln" (e vor l)  geschrieben. Obwohl die Suchmaschine nicht "Googel" sondern "Google" heißt, ist "googlen" falsch. Nur "googeln" ist richtig.

Comment: Okay habe es berichtigt.

Answer (score 0):

1. etwas (im Netz) suchen
2. etwas retouchieren/etwas ist retouchiert
3. etwas (mit duck-duch-go) suchen