# Brand names which are used instead of the original name of the product?

Tags: curiosity

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Wann darf man Markennamen bevorzugen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/503/wann-darf-man-markennamen-bevorzugen)*

There are some famous brands, whose names overtook the name of the original product and when the name of the brand is said, everybody understands what is meant.

In Germany, I only know two examples;

> **Tempo** is used, when **Taschentuch** is meant

or

> **Tupperware** is used, when **Essensbehälter** is meant

What are other examples?

Comment: Very closely related (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/503/wann-darf-man-markennamen-bevorzugen

Comment: @Takkat Thank you very much. They are the same question.

Comment: See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei

Comment: The link to the related question alone contains more than 10 examples. I guess there are even more than 100 words in colloquial that are valid in respect to your question.

Comment: Reopened because the majority of close voters voted for *duplicate* which is not a valid close reason here. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei **and** https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate.

Comment: Be careful, though... I may be overly picky, but if you ask me for a Tempo and I only have a different brand of handkerchief, I may tell you I don't have one, assuming you want that specific brand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI these words are called **Deonym**.

> **Googeln** (not Googlen) is used, when **mit einer Suchmaschine suchen** is meant

[Duden: Googeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/googeln)

> **Knirps** is used, when **ein kleiner Regenschirm** is meant

[Duden: Knirps](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Knirps#Bedeutung2)

> **INBUS** is used, when **Innensechskant** is meant

[Duden: INBUS](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Inbus)

There's a big [list](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deonyme_nach_Sachgebiet) on Wikipedia with many of these words.

Comment: Very interesting point :) +1

Comment: Ich kenne es als **googeln** ;)

Comment: @Takkat Stimmt! Interessant, dass sich das Wort vom eigentlichen Markennamen unterscheidet. [Duden Googeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/googeln)

Comment: Jepp: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12075/webw%c3%b6rter-neu-erfinden-f%c3%bcr-google-duckduckgo-photoshop

Comment: Interessant auch, dass das Verb *googeln* es innerhalb von 20 Jahren in den allgemeinen Wortschatz geschafft hat, das Verb *duden* (was im Prinzip dasselbe bedeuten könnte, nur in Papier) auch nach 120 Jahren nicht. ;)

Comment: @tofro Ich dude, du dudst, er/sie/es dudt.. Schwer auszusprechen :D

Comment: @AdInfinitum und der Dude dudet....

Comment: @tofro Wer dudet gut wie der Dude dudet.. So können wir bald die neuere Version von Barbara erfinden :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVxZdgtB3V4

Answer (score 1):

I have found some other examples, which the answer of the German version of this question does not have.

> Post-it -> Klebezettel
>
> Edding -> Filzstifte, Marker und andere Schreibgeräte
>
> Labello -> Lippenpflegestift
>
> Polaroid -> Sofortbildkameras
>
> Fanta -> Orangenlimonade
>
> Sprite -> Zitronenlimonade

Comment: "Fanta" habe ich bisher auch noch in keiner Liste gesehen.

Comment: @Em1 Ich habe Fanta und Sprite zu der Liste hinzugefügt. Übrigens, du hattest recht. Am Anfang dachte ich nicht, dass diese Liste viele Einträge hat.

Comment: Wie so oft variiert aber gerade bei den hier genannten Begriffen das, was konkret darunter verstanden wird, von Person zu Person.

Comment: Gestern beim Reifenwechsel ist mir noch ein schöner Begriff eingefallen: Caramba (und zwar nicht das spanische Caramba), das ein Schmiermittel bezeichnet — https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriechöl